# Firebase scheduled function triggered on update/deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have some unexpected behavior with a firebase scheduled cloud function. The function is set to run every night at 4am, and this works as expected. When deploying cloud functions with firebase cli deploy, this function is executed immediately. Doesn't matter if it was changed or not.

I have been trying to figure out when this happens as it doesn't happen on every deploy. It seems to happen only on the first deploy each day. If I deploy cloud functions again, after a deploy is finished, the scheduled function is not executed again.

Is there any time a scheduled function is expected to run immediately on deploy? How can I prevent this from happening?

---

Edit: Added example code.
I also did some more testing. The unwanted executions are somehow linked to the cron schedule.

I changed the function to .schedule('*/15 * * * *'), every 15th minute, with the following result

13.00 - function executed on schedule
13.05 - deployed functions again. Scheduled function executed again
13.10 - deployed functions again. No function executed
13.15 - function executed on schedule

So I would say the first deploy after the scheduled execution causes the function to execute again, and following deploys do not.
In each deploy I updated a console.log and I can see that it's the PREVIOUS version that is executed.

I can also mention everything is written in typescript 
firebase-admin: 8.9.0, 
firebase-functions: 3.3.0 
firebase-tools: 7.7.0

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const scheduledFunction = functions
  .region('europe-west2')
  .runWith({ memory: functions.VALID_MEMORY_OPTIONS[3], timeoutSeconds: functions.MAX_TIMEOUT_SECONDS })
  .pubsub
  .schedule('0 4 * * *') // Every day 04.00
  .timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
  .retryConfig({ retryCount: 2 })
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    // function code...
});
```

index.ts

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

// Initialize firebase admin
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

import { scheduledFunction } from './scheduledFunction';
export { scheduledFunction };

...import other functions
```

Comment: Can you run the deploy with `--debug` and see if it talks about deleting and recreating the schedule? It shouldn't assuming you're not changing the schedule but that might be the cause...

Comment: Could you edit the question with the complete, minimal code that you deploy that causes this behavior?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Running deploy with --debug. I couldn't find anything about deleting and recreating schedule. HTTP REQUEST PATCH cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/… timeZone=Europe/Stockholm, schedule=0 4 * * *, retryCount=2, name=projects..., topicName=projects/..., scheduled=true

Comment: @MichaelBleigh are you suggesting that changing the schedule will automatically trigger the function?  Is there documentation around this you could point to?  I am seeing the same behavior as the OP.  I am unable to predict when it will auto-run an updated function.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you be more specific about what else the OP could provide that would make this an MVCE? I am having this exact same problem and have been having it for a long time. I've been ignoring it, but yesterday it emailed all my users when I updated the related function. I'm also happy to publish my function and related details in a separate question if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: @jmargolisvt The OP didn't at-mention me, so I didn't see the update. I suggest sending your observations to Firebase support so they can investigate.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support